# Android LiveData contains value but when assigning to variable it is null

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am retrieving data from Room database and returing it as LiveData. When I am putting that data inside a variable in the activity it is showing null but the Live data has the value. What is the problem?

[image: variable it null oberver.it has value]

```
var loginCredentials: User? = null
                DBUtils.with(this).getDB().userDao()
                    .loginValidation(accoutNo, pincode)
                    .observe(this) {
                        loginCredentials = it
                        Log.e("Login it", it.toString())
                    }

                Log.e("Login variable", loginCredentials.toString())
```

I am guessing the value is on another thread. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are showing the below log outside the observer

```
Log.e("Login variable", loginCredentials.toString())
```

And **loginCredentials** may be not assigned because livedata observer does not trigger yet, and above log statement called before the observer trigger.

You need to do your task inside the observer so that you have value in **loginCredentials** variable.

```
var loginCredentials: User? = null
DBUtils.with(this).getDB().userDao()
    .loginValidation(accoutNo, pincode)
    .observe(this) {
        loginCredentials = it
        Log.e("Login it", it.toString())
        Log.e("Login variable", loginCredentials.toString())
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it's working on another thread. you can't pass the value like this. it's an async process.

You have to create a live-data observer and observe that particular element on activity or fragment. that's how it will work.

Steps which you can follow :-

1. Init variables :-

```
private val _catValuesList = MutableLiveData<List<Values>>()
val catValuesList: LiveData<List<Values>> = _catValuesList
```

2. postvalue in response :-

```
_catValuesList.postValue(catResponse.data)
```

3. Observe :-

```
viewModel.catValuesList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { list ->  }
```